# Working on an autopopulate and cant get it to work

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Having troubles getting this to work my problem is when I am querying my Visual model to get information to auto populate for user..

This is my model for visual

```
 class Visual < ActiveRecord::Base

   establish_connection :vtest

   self.table_name = 'employee'

   Visual.inheritance_column = 'inheritance_type'

   belongs_to :user
 end
```

This is my model for user

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :visual
```

This is my user controller that does the action auto populate when I have it look at... When I use where('id = ?', "#{emp_id}') I get this error NameError (undefined local variable or method `emp_id' for #): But when I change it to .where('id = ?', "BILL") it works....I have a form that when they enter in information this will auto complete the rest of page for them but each person has a different emp_id.

However when I do this Visual.where('id = ?', "#{@emp_id}%") I get this is works but nothing shows up   Visual Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "EMPLOYEE".* FROM "EMPLOYEE"  WHERE (id = '%')

```
class UserController < ApplicationController


def populate_form
  @visual = Visual.where('id = ?', "#{emp_id}")
  @emp_first_name = @visual.first_name

  render :json => {

      :emp_first_name => @emp_first_name,
  }

 end
```

table information for user

```
 emp_id
```

table information for visual

```
 id 
 first_name
```

emp_id and id are the same thing example @user.emp_id = Bill, @visual.id = Bill.

I tried this now but now I got this error   Visual Load (4.7ms)  SELECT "EMPLOYEE".* FROM "EMPLOYEE"  WHERE (id = NULL)

```
def self.emp_id
  @emp_id = emp_id
end


def populate_form
  @visual = Visual.where('id = ?', @emp_id)
```

Comment: `emp_id` isn't defined in your controller. Where is it coming from? A form? If so, then you need to retrieve it from the `params` hash. using `@emp_id` is an instance variable that has nothing in it. And out of curiosity, why are you using `Visual.inheritance_column = 'inheritance_type'` instead of `self.inheritance_column = 'inheritance_type'`?

Answer (score 0):

You simply didn't define emp_id in your controller. and @emp_id query works because it is evaluated to 'nil' (not defined instance variables are nils)

Comment: I updated the question with what I just tired now I get that error. @Fenec

Comment: I tried this  visual = Visual.find_by_id('BILL') and it worked the problem is I want it to take the value of my text box called emp_id and take that value and compare it with whats in my employee table cant seem to figure this one out. @Fenec

Comment: I tried this visual = Visual.find_by_id('BILL') and it worked the problem is I want it to take the value of my text box called emp_id and take that value and compare it with whats in my employee table cant seem to figure this one out  @lurker